# React-native : How many milliseconds will take for onLongPress(Prop of TouchableOpacity) to be called?

Tags: android, react-native, long-press

`onLongPress` is called when `View` is tapped and hold for some time. But the time to hold seems a bit longer in `react-native` app compared to native `android` app. I tested same thing in my `android` phone with `Contacts` app where `LongPress` action is a bit faster.

Hence, I would like to know how many milliseconds will take for `onLongPress` to be called? And is there anyway to decrease the time?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

There is a major difference between a React Native application and a native Android application.

React Native works in a way that when you are using native UI elements, it has to communicate the actions taken on these elements to the native logic, which takes time. This is called a [bridge](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-react-native-bridge-concept-e9526066ddb8).

This bridge is used to translate the JS calls and invoke the native's underlying APIs and UI elements.

I am guessing this is why you are a seeing a slight time difference between a React Native application and a native Android one.

Answer (score 0):

React Native provides this prop for **`Touchable`**,

```
delayLongPress
```

this delays the long press for the amount of time(ms) you specify.

you can go to definition of `TouchableOpacity` by

**ctr+click** on `TouchableOpacity` *or* right click on `TouchableOpacity` and select go to definition.(VS Code)

and see more information about this prop and use this props as per your use case.